# feathersjs/sequelizejs -> MODEL is not associated with MODEL

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs

I have two folders under the 'services' folder. They are working calling the service individually. Now I want expand one model to include the related model and this is giving an error 'info: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Model' of undefined'

The database exists, sql server, and the relations are there too.

file services\mic\activity\index.js

```
'use strict';

const service = require('feathers-sequelize');
const activity = require('./activity-model');
const hooks = require('./hooks/index');

module.exports = function () {
    const app = this;

    const options = {
        Model: activity(app.get('mic_sequelize'))
    };

    app.use('/mic/activity', service(options));

    const activityService = app.service('/mic/activity');

    activityService.before(hooks.before);
    activityService.after(hooks.after);
};
```

file services\mic\activity\activity-model.js

```
'use strict';

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    const activity = sequelize.define('activity', {
        activity_pk: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        activity_plan_pk: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: false
        },
        change_order_pk: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            unique: false
        },
        description: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: false
        },
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        paranoid: false,
        timestamps  : false,
        underscored : false,
        tableName: 'Activity',
        classMethods: {
            associate() {
                activity.belongsTo(sequelize.models.activity_plan, {
                    allowNull: true,
                    as: 'activity_plan'
                });
                activity.belongsTo(sequelize.models.change_order, {
                    allowNull: false,
                    as: 'change_order'
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return activity;
};
```

file services\mic\activity\hooks\index.js

```
'use strict';

const globalHooks = require('../../../../hooks');
const hooks = require('feathers-hooks');
const auth = require('feathers-authentication').hooks;

exports.before = {
    all: [],
    find: [
        getRelatedInfo()
    ],
    get: [
        getRelatedInfo()
    ],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
};

exports.after = {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
};


function getRelatedInfo() {
    return function (hook) {
        hook.params.sequelize = {
            attributes: [
                'activity_pk',
                'activity_plan_pk',
                'change_order_pk',
                ['description', 'activity_description'],
                ['id', 'activity_id']
            ],
            include: [
                {
                    model: hook.app.services.activity_plan.Model,
                    as: 'activity_plan',
                    required: false,
                    attributes: [
                        ['description', 'activity_plan_description'],
                        ['id', 'activity_plan_id']
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    };
    return Promise.resolve(hook);
}
```

file services\mic\activity_plan\index.js

```
'use strict';

const service = require('feathers-sequelize');
const activity_plan = require('./activity_plan-model');
const hooks = require('./hooks/index');

module.exports = function () {
    const app = this;

    const options = {
        Model: activity_plan(app.get('mic_sequelize'))
    };

    app.use('/mic/activity_plan', service(options));

    const activityplanService = app.service('/mic/activity_plan');

    activityplanService.before(hooks.before);
    activityplanService.after(hooks.after);
};
```

file services\mic\activity_plan\activity_plan-model.js

```
'use strict';

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    const activity_plan = sequelize.define('activity_plan', {
        activity_plan_pk: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        description: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: false
        },
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        paranoid: false,
        timestamps  : false,
        underscored : false,
        tableName: 'Activity_Plan',
        classMethods: {
            associate() {
                activity_plan.hasMany(sequelize.models.activity, {
                    as: 'activity_plan',
                    foreignKey: 'activity_plan_pk',
                    targetKey: 'activity_plan_pk'
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return activity_plan;
};
```

file service\mic\activity_plan\hooks\index.js

```
'use strict';

const globalHooks = require('../../../../hooks');
const hooks = require('feathers-hooks');
const auth = require('feathers-authentication').hooks;

exports.before = {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
};

exports.after = {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
};
```

**Question**

I think somewhere I have a misconfiguration. I used a working example app of my self where the services doesn't have subfolders and the relation is made the same way. That is working. Any idea where the issue is?

**Solving**

Okay. So I moved activity and activity_Plan back to the root of services without changing anything except file locations. Same error. THen I changed the paths for the service (removed '/mic') and now I get 'activity_plan' is not associated with 'activity'.

Okay, now I reverted my test and have this line `model: hook.app.service('/mic/activity_plan').Model`. Then I thought of something. I have custom primary keys, so I need to do something in the hasMany, belongsTo parts looking into that

So now I made a second database which is made through sequelize (the tables) strangly, exact same problem.

If I look at this line `at Model.validateIncludedElement (D:\Workspace\Projects\01. Live Customers\Mexon Technology\Projects - Mexon\MexonInControl\MultiFunctionalPortal\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:558:11)` and then in the code it points to, it may well be an issue with the naming of my models in combination with the line `model: hook.app.service('/mfp/sys_metadata').Model` in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear. I totally forgot to initialize the associations in the index.js file of the service subfolder:

```
 Object.keys(sequelize.models).forEach(function(modelName) {
        if ("associate" in sequelize.models[modelName]) {
            sequelize.models[modelName].associate();
        }
    });

    sequelize.sync(
        {
            force: false
        }
    );
```